# Crontab job executed every day instead every month

Tags: linux, shell, cron

Three days ago I installed the following crontab job with crontab -e:

```
# execute weekly
0 2 2-31 * 7 sh /home/user/folder/myscript.sh week > /home/user/.crontablog/crontab.log
```

It's supposed to be executed every sunday night at 2am except the 1st of the month. However it's executed every night at 2am. What's my mistake? I tried 0 instead of 7 for Sunday with the same result :/

Thank you.

Comment: Try `0` for Sunday, instead of `7`?

Comment: Why are you specifying `2-21` for the day?  Looks like it won't run if the first of the month is a Sunday.

Comment: Steve Summit, thank you. I've just edited the post to say I have already tried 0 with no success.

Comment: I think you want `0 2 * * 7` to run at 2:00am every Sunday.  7 and 0 are equivalent.  (And yes, I use something just like that for once-a-week jobs.)

Comment: 2-31 because I have another job to be executed the 1st of the month so it's ok to avoid the day 1.

Comment: 2-31 * * 7 are or conditions, not 'and' conditions.

Comment: Ok Dirk Eddelbuettel. So there must be a conflict when I specify the day of the month and the day of the week?

Comment: it looks to me that this says every sunday and every day from the 2 to the 31

Comment: Well, the intention was to specify just sundays from the 2nd to 31th

Answer (score 2):

Since the format of crontab is like this:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

To execute it every week on Sunday irrespective of the month you need to write it like this:

```
0 2 * * 7 sh /home/user/folder/myscript.sh week > /home/user/.crontablog/crontab.log
```

Answer (score 1):

first you can analyze the content of /var/log/cron, grepping for your script to see what is going on.

I suggest you use the following syntax

```
0 2 * * sun /home/user/folder/myscript.sh week
```

having given the +x permission on the script file.
Cheers

Comment: I've tried this syntax tonight and it has worked fine. However, I will try the solution proposed by chaos because I'd like to avoid the execution on the 1st of the month.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you respecified your question in the comments you need to do TWO things:

- as I said above, use `0 2 * * 7 to run at 2:00am every Sunday`; 7 and 0 are equivalent
- *inside your shell script* use an additional test to quietly exit on the first of the month.

That test could be as simple as

```
test $(date +%d) == "01" && exit
```

but you could of course also make it a proper `if ...` with more `echo` and verbosity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the script every sunday night at 2am, **but only if it's not the first day in the month**, then you have to use this syntax:

```
0 2 * * 0 /usr/bin/test $(/bin/date +\%e) -ne 1 && your_command
```

The `test` utilliy finally check if it's the first day in month and `your_command` is only exected if it's not.